# No Ajax response even though PHP file set up correctly

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple sign up mailing list form.  It sends the user's email address to a store-address.php file.  I use jQuery's ajax object to send a request to the php file and then receive a response.

The problem is I am not getting a response from the php file.  I tried setting the cache to false in the request.  I also tried send the information through the URL like so:

http://www.fifthtribe.com/inc/store-address.php?ajax=true&cache=false&email=test4%40gmail.com

When I do it that way it works and gives me a reponse.  But when I do it through ajax it doesn't give me a response.  This is from Firebug:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here's snippets from my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mlist">
<form id="mlist_form" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Join" />
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
/* Add to mailing list */           
$("#mlist_form").submit( function(e){
    //$('#response').append('<div id="thanks-mce"><div id="mce-arrow"></div>Thanks for signing up!</div>');
    var email = escape( $('#email').val() );
    e.preventDefault();

    data = {
        "ajax" : "true",
        "email" : email,
        "cache" : "false"
}

    $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",           
            url: 'inc/store-address.php',
            data: data,
            success: function( msg ){
                // successfully signed up
                $('#response').html( msg );
                $('#email').val('');
            },
            error: function( err ){
                // error while signing up
                $('#response').html('Error: Is your email correct?');
            }
    });

    return false;

});
```

**PHP:**
        function storeAddress(){

```
    // Validation
    if(!$_GET['email']){ return "No email address provided"; } 

    if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $_GET['email'])) {
        return "Email address is invalid"; 
    }

    require_once('MCAPI.class.php');
    // grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
    $api = new MCAPI('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us4');

    // grab your List's Unique Id by going to http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/
    // Click the "settings" link for the list - the Unique Id is at the bottom of that page. 
    $list_id = "xxxxxxxx";

    if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], '') === true) {
        // It worked!   
        return 'Success! Check your email to confirm sign up.';
    }else{
            // An error ocurred, return error message   
            return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
    }

}

    // If being called via ajax, autorun the function
    if($_GET['ajax']){ echo storeAddress(); }
?>
```

Comment: in the php code try `print_r($_REQUEST);` and make sure your data is there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You realize that your PHP script is using `GET` method but your jQuery code is using the `POST` method right?

If the information is being posted to PHP, PHP will need to use `$_POST` to retrieve it. This explains why the URL method using `$_GET` works but the jQuery `POST` doesn't.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I knew it must have been something I overlooked.  It always helps to get a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using $_GET instead of $_POST.  Try echoing out the contents of $_REQUEST to see what that holds.

Answer (score 1):

Debug your script!

Place an alert in the success and error parts of your script and then you will know whether the AJAX is working.

If not, you can then work your way up the document and see where the problem is.

**In addition, the error here is quite simple. You are using $_GET in PHP and you are POSTING your data using AJAX, this will not show an error. Although the PHP document will not process your request because it is not being fed any parameters.**